# Google Oauth Unverified error despite successful verification

Tags: google-sheets, google-oauth

I have integrated with Google OAuth to sign in and read data from Google Sheets. Though I have followed the verification process and got my app verified, I am still getting an unverified error as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Image showing verification error]

Could not find a relevant help/support forum as well. Any guidance on how to debug further?

Screenshot confirming App verification:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the very late answer here. I'm going to leave one because I'm sure others will run into this issue.

Google will only verify the scopes that you name in the [OAuth consent screen](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent/edit) settings. If you haven't included a sensitive scope in that list, they will verify the branding for your app, but not the scopes.

Nowadays, Google's UI has been updated. The relevant section currently looks like this:

[image: Google's sensitive scopes section]

You'll need to include at least one sensitive scope in this section. Mine is read access to your contacts. Yours may be access to your Google Sheets data. Either way, you'll need to explain how you will use this data.